# is the equality $\langle Q, V diag(\lambda)V^T\rangle = \langle V^TQV, diag(\lambda)\rangle $ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I am wondering if the following equaility hold.

\begin{align*}
      \langle Q, V diag(\lambda)V^T\rangle =  \langle V^TQV, diag(\lambda)\rangle
\end{align*}
where $Q\in \mathbb{S}_n, V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},$ and $diag(\lambda)$ is the diagnoal matrix with components $\lambda_i, i=1,\dots, t$ on the diagonal.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this the Gram-Schmidt inner product?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $D = \text{diag}(\lambda)$.
Assuming you mean the Gram-Schmidt inner product, we have
$$
\langle Q, V DV^T\rangle =  \\
\operatorname{trace}(Q(VDV^T)^T) = \\
\operatorname{trace}((QVD^T)V^T) = \\
\operatorname{trace}(V^T(QVD^T)) = \\
\langle V^TQV, D\rangle
$$
so, yes.